# Hide a Bootstrap collapse trigger button after

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button to trigger a collapsed dive and open it. I would like to make the button disappear once it's been clicked.

Button:

```
 <button id="show-more-home" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" class="btn btn-default"><i class="ion-chevron-down"></i> </button>
```

I tried this js but no go:

```
<script>
  $("#show-more-home").addClass('hidden');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the jQuery `.hide()` function:

```
<script>
  $("body").on('click','#show-more-home', function(){ $(this).hide(); });
</script>
```

or if you have a `.hidden` class like:

```
.hidden {display:none !important;}
```

you can also hide it like:

```
<script>
  $("body").on('click','#show-more-home',function(){ $(this).addClass('hidden'); });
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason that still won't hide it.

Comment: @RachelS I have made a  mistake. check the edited answer.

Comment: This works when I test in bootply but it won't work on my site. Any idea of what would hold back something like this from working? I have no styles or anything going on.

Comment: @RachelS I edited the code again replacing `.click` with `.on`. also make sure that jQuery is loaded when you run this code

Comment: You're a genius! That was the problem. It was not loaded after jquery.